# IOError: [Errno 0] Error while writing to output of Powershell in VSCode

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code, colorama

This is the error I get in VSCode when running docker-compose.

```
PS D:\Work\Imho\Api> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
Creating network "api_default" with the default driver
Pulling ignite (apacheignite/ignite:latest)...
latest: Pulling from apacheignite/ignite
5040bd298390: Pulling fs layer
fce5728aad85: Pulling fs layer

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 68, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 118, in perform_command
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 926, in up
  File "compose\project.py", line 401, in up
  File "compose\service.py", line 305, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose\service.py", line 1001, in pull
  File "compose\progress_stream.py", line 37, in stream_output
  File "codecs.py", line 370, in write
  File "site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 40, in write
  File "site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 141, in write
  File "site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 169, in write_and_convert
  File "site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 174, in write_plain_text
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  ignite:
    image: apacheignite/ignite
```

This error only happens on one of my 3 machines, so I have no idea what causes it. Resetting to factory defaults or reinstalling docker and vscode doesn't help. Without docker compose the image is pulling and then working fine. All the machines are on windows 10 and latest stable docker installed.

Here is the [issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5019) I opened on github. It appeared that this behavior only occurs in VSCode powershell console, but not in regular powershell console. The solution with changing encoding suggested there didn't help.

Comment: its like, why are you making things harder for yourself...

Comment: I want to make things easier and to run only vscode and not vscode and powershell separately =)

Comment: vscode powershell shell is such a garbage, no idea why would you want to use that

Comment: I guess because nobody told me it is a garbage before

Comment: @Lanayx this has nothing to do with docker compose as the Github issue suggests

Comment: @vedarthk thanks for the edits

Comment: I had a similar issue under windows. In my case the project contains some non UTF-8 files that seems to be the issue. Same command, same code by using git bash solved the problem as mentioned in the bug you opened in github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Update to 1803 on Windows 10. If you can't update, use external command prompt.

The same thing happens to me with Python scripts. Apparently, this is a Windows Update issue:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36630#issuecomment-359969098

Edit: My workaround due to my company restricting updates is to use external terminal in VS Code